# What should I do with benchmark in Go

Tags: go, benchmarking

I understand what benchmark is, how to write, and how to execute benchmark in Go.
But I'm not really understanding what should I do with it.

Like test, I should create test case to test every function I created, so that I can confirm if the function works as I expected. And if I have further change in other place, I can run unit tests to confirm if everything works well.

What about benchmark? E.g. there are many sort algorithm, like bubble sort and merge sort. But there will only be 1 implementation in the app code base with signature `sort(arr []int)`. So I should create benchmarks functions for those algorithms then copy & paste the implementation whenever I found the best fit?

So, what should I do with benchmark in Go? Welcome every idea from daily to performance optimization.

Comment: If your _measurements_ show that some part of your application is "too slow": Write a benchmark, benchmark the current state, make trail optimisations, benchmark them, see what helps and improve your code.

Comment: Stop marking my questions invalid. New comers dont need code snippets for copy and past. They need concepts! No wonder ppl mocking on programmers that they cant write code without stackoverflow, even themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benchmarks are tests too. No wonder they placed in testing package. As you correctly said general unit tests (`testing.T`) allow to check if some refactoring hasn't break logic of function. But in highload systems there is another criteria besides to correctly working logic. It is time of processing of some logic. Benchmarks allow you to check that refactoring that you made
had not made your function work slower.

Comment: Which means `testing.B` is actually for some concrete performance criteria, instead of choosing among implementations, like bubble sort and merge sort I mentioned in the post.

Comment: I don't really understand your  analogy about implementations of sorting algorithms. You can have different implementation of sort algorithms if you want. You can make bubbleSort function and mergeSort function.

 The purpose of benchmarks is similar to purpose of unit tests despite the fact that unit tests check correctness of business logic but benchmarks tests execution time of function